# How to make div inside table fill up remaining space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Given the HTML structure below, how do I make `td.expand` fill up the remaining vertical space of `#outer`? I've tried various solutions (including Flexbox), but nothing worked for me. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with the two tables, so assume the HTML structure cannot be changed. Also, assume that `#outer` is inside a modal that can be resized, so its height is dynamic (i.e., as the user resizes the modal, the height of `#outer` is changed, and `td.expand` should continuously fill up the vertical space such that the header and footer will always be at the top and bottom of `#outer`, respectively.

```css
#outer {
  height: 400px; /* dynamic */
  background: skyblue;
}
.fixed {
  height: 20px;
}
header,
footer {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="container">
    <header>Header</header>
    <table class="outer-table">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <table class="inner-table">
              <tr><td class="expand">This should fill up remaining vertical space.</td></tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="fixed"><td>Fixed height</td></tr>
      <tr class="fixed"><td>Fixed height</td></tr>
    </table>
    <footer>Footer (should be pushed to the bottom)</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

The output should look like this, where `td.expand` fills up the remaining space of `#outer`:

[image]

Comment: I don't think I understand your question well, you want the footer to be on the down edge of *skyblue*

Comment: is such a result needed? - https://ibb.co/MCCTK5B

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov but he said that "*how do him make the red box fill up the remaining vertical space* " and in your link the red box I can see it fill in horizontally space

Comment: @thdoan No idea what you are asking. The entire page is blue... what is `the remaining height of #outer` What remaining height? Please explain in more detail.

Comment: show the desired result with a screenshot

Comment: Sorry for confusion guys, I'm photoshopping what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played a little with flex. Did you need such a result? The red block is stretchable.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.outer-table {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}

.outer-table > tbody {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
}

.outer-table > tbody > tr:first-of-type {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.outer-table > tbody > tr > td {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

#outer {
  height: 400px;
  background: skyblue;
}
header,
footer {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.content {
  background: red;
  flex: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="container">
    <header>Header</header>
    <table class="outer-table">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <table class="inner-table">
              <tr><td class="expand">This should fill up remaining height of #outer (blue)</td></tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td>Fixed height</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Fixed height</td></tr>
    </table>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice one ^^. This works for my case since we are no longer supporting legacy IE.

Answer (score 1):

Just calculate the the `height` by subtracting occupied `height` by `footer` and `header` and two `tr` from the parent `height`

```css
#outer {
  height: 400px;
  background: skyblue;
}

header,
footer {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.content {
  background: red;
  height: 245px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="container">
    <header>Header</header>
    <table class="outer-table">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <table class="inner-table">
              <tr>
                <td class="expand">This should fill up remaining height of #outer (blue)</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fixed height</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fixed height</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for input, but you reminded me of another requirement: the #outer height is dynamic as it can be resized. As the user resizes #outer, the red area should continue to fill out the remaining vertical space. I'll update the question.